# Loop through multiple levels of subfolders and convert csv.gz files to csv

Tags: python, csv, jupyter

I have thousands of csv.gz files that are arranged into multiple levels of folders and subfolders. A snapshot of the file arrangement is:

'Folder' - 'Subfolder1' - 'Subfolder2' - 'csv.gz files'

I would like to set up code that goes through each folder and subfolder and extracts the csv files while keeping the csv.gz file.

I've tried the following code:

```
import gzip    
import os

directory = os.getcwd()

for dirpath, dir, files in os.walk(top=directory):
    for file in files:
        with gzip.open(file, 'rt') as f:
            data = f.read()
    with open(file[:-3], 'wt') as f:
      f.write(data)
```

However, I receive the following error message: "OSError: Not a gzipped file (b'{\n')". Does anyone know why I am receiving this error or whether there is another way to unzip these files? I'm quite new to coding and Python is the first language I've tried to use to so any help would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Are you on windows or linux? If it's linux, you can just do a `find -name '*.gz' | xargs gunzip`

Comment: I'm on linux. I just tried the command but the '*.gz' returns an invalid syntax error.

Comment: That is strange! It's working when I tested. Can you post the (truncated) output of `find -name '*.gz'`? If that also didn't work just the output of `find`.

Comment: Sorry I get the same error using "find -name '*.gz'" and when I try just 'find' it returns an error of: "NameError: name 'find' is not defined." Am I supposed to install a package of some sort?

Comment: ah, you are running this in python itself? These are just linux commands. So open up a terminal and `cd` to your directory. Then issue these commands at the terminal. I was just answering to your question on whether there is any other way to unzip these files.

Comment: `cd ~/Desktop` will get you to `Desktop`. `~` stands for your home folder. It will be same as `/home/<userid>`. You can use the command `cd ~/Desktop/ && find -name '*.gz' | xargs gunzip` directly in a terminal to do what you want.

Comment: Nvm I've worked it out! But now I get the following error: "find: illegal option -- n
usage: find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]
       find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]"

Comment: Can you just copy paste the above code? There is no `--` there is only one `-`!

Comment: Even when I copy and paste the above code I get the same error. And if I remove the '-' I get an error saying no file or directory.

Comment: Try `cd ~/Desktop/ && find . -name '*.gz' | xargs gunzip`. If your find is `gnu` version, it would have defaulted the search to current working directory. I think your find is `bsd` version. Hence the extra `.`.

Comment: Yes that worked perfectly! Thank you so so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be using Linux commands is the easier approach. Try the following

```
find <your directory path here> -name '*.gz' | xargs gunzip
```